# Date Comparison In Entity Framework Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to compare dates in Entity Framework 6 LINQ Query.

```
var bookings = context.Bookings.Include("BookingItems").Where(x=>x.IsDeleted == false && DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BookingDate).Value,DateTime.Now.Date)==0).ToList();
```

However its resulting in Exception:

```
"The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."
```

**I just want to compare dates by trimming time part.**

Any suggestions how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq can't translate some native .Net code into Sql so try to use DateTime.Now function and other .Net function outside Linq query and then reference it in query.

```
String currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

var bookings = context.Bookings.Include("BookingItems").Where(x=>x.IsDeleted == false && DateTime.Compare((x.BookingDate).Value.Date,currentTime)==0).ToList();
```

I haven't run though there might be some syntax error, but try anyway

Comment: can you please give an example of how to reference it in query

Comment: this thing did the trick
    DateTime temp = DateTime.Now.Date;
                var bookings = context.Bookings.Include("BookingItems").Where(x=>x.IsDeleted == false && DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BookingDate).Value,temp)==0).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Linq to sql or sql does not have implemination DateTime.Compare

Try converting to collection.

```
var bookings = context.Bookings.Include("BookingItems").ToList().Where(x=>x.IsDeleted == false && DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.BookingDate).Value,DateTime.Now.Date)==0).ToList();
```

Comment: now this exception: {"This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."}