# Entity Framework DateTime Comparison in Query - Possible Bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

Suppose you have a database table such that

```
public partial class myTable
{
    [Key]
    public Guid rowID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? eventTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose you're looking for a data in there that has happened 5 or fewer days ago:

```
DateTime dTVal = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
var event = db.myTable.Where(evt => evt.eventTime >= dTVal);
```

The above query will *NOT* work. The reason being is that DateTime.Now gives hours, minutes and seconds of course. However, instead of giving an error from sql or the like the results are just returned with 0 rows.

In order to resolve and retrieve the expected data:

```
var dtVal = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).Date; // This wouldn't work in the LINQ to Entities query because AddDays() method...
var events = db.myTable.Where(evt => evt.eventTime >= dtVal);
```

Perhaps my relative newness with EF is to blame, but this seems VERY unintuitive and somewhat a pain, because Intellisense doesn't pick it up as anything other than `DateTime?` and the hover tooltip on the property is also `DateTime? myTable.eventTime...` thereby causing me to have to go find every date property I am comparing against to make sure I a converting that correctly.

Should not EF take the `DateTime` object in this case and convert it to the correct format prior to constructing the query, and throw an exception prior actually performing the query?

Does anyone have a familiarity with this type of problem and what have you done in the past to work with it?

[Similar *Answered* Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684269/date-comparison-in-entity-framework-linq-query)

Comment: If `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5)` amounts to 2016-12-22 17:48:15Z, your first query yields all events on or after this moment in time, nothing wrong with it. A DateTime value doesn't have a format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is to use a `DateTime.Date` for date2 type entities.

```
var compareDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).Date;
```

Thanks.